# Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'testsdk': No module named 'jsonpickle' with Python script using AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-3.7, jsonpickle

My Python script has been tested on multiple local computers and works as expected. But when the script is zipped up and uploaded to AWS Lambda I get `Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'testsdk': No module named 'jsonpickle'` when I test the code. `testsdk` is the desired python file that should be executed.

The python version on my local PC is 3.7.0 which is the same Python version as AWS Lambda.

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and solved it by correcting the directory structure.

Inside the lambda function are two equal folder names. I fixed the issue by deleting the first folder.

[image: directory structure]